# Run create function code without SQLCMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I have DDL code to create a function that runs flawlessly from sqlcmd and other specific SQL Server clients:

```
/*
 * Émulo de la función LPAD() de Oracle
 */
CREATE FUNCTION LPAD
(
    @cadena VARCHAR(MAX), -- Texto de partida
    @tamano INT,          -- Tamaño de la cadena resultante
    @relleno CHAR         -- Carácter de relleno
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    return REPLICATE(@relleno, @tamano - LEN(@cadena)) + @cadena;
END
GO
```

However, it won't typically run from cross-DBMS clients (SQL Fiddle, DBeaver, HeidiSQL...):

> [102] Incorrect syntax near '@cadena'.

I suspect it's got to do with the `GO` batch separator not being implemented. If that's the case, is there an alternative syntax?

Comment: You need to tell those clients that you are using a different delimiter. In SQL Fiddle you can do that with the dropdown that initially shows `[ ; ]`  below the source editor. Other SQL clients should have similar options.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did change to `[go]` compile the schema but still cant use the function, what else is missing? [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f008/3)

Comment: In SQL Server you **have** to prefix user written functions with the schema/owner: `SELECT dbo.LPAD('hola', 10, '+');` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9f008/4

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Of course you're absolutely right about SQL Fiddle (I must be blind!). Should I assume that how to set a delimiter is entirely up to the client and not part of standard SQL Server syntax?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: the standard statement delimiter in SQL is `;`.  But when running code blocks with "embedded" `;` then yes, it's completely up to the SQL client on how this is done.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think we have an answer, though scattered throughout question comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up my comments:

The standard delimiter in SQL is the `;`.

However, when running a code block that contains embedded semicolons (e.g. when creating a stored procedure) the standard delimiter cannot be applied as in that case the *block* wouldn't be sent as a single statement.

For those cases the SQL client usually has some way of defining an alternate delimiter that marks the end of a block and usually has a higher precedence than the `;`

Microsoft calls this "alternate delimiter" the "batch separated" and decided to use `GO` for this and all Microsoft tools stick to that. In SSMS this batch separator can actually be configured to something else.

Oracle's SQL*Plus (and SQL Developer) use `/` for this.

Other SQL clients allow a dynamic definition inside a SQL script typically using `delimiter` (or something similar) to change the delimiter for subsequent statements.

As I have never used DBeaver or HeidiSQL I cannot tell how this is done in those SQL clients.

Comment: I still haven't haven't the chance to test whether they actually work but separator is a connection setting in DBeaver and a button that opens a text box in HeidiSQL. I hadn't noticed before because I didn't know I had to look for it.